# what is the regex for getting statuscode in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, status

Below is the string I am getting from server and I want to get Status code

```
program 40006932 version 1 protocol tcp NOT registered
Transient program number selected = 40006932
TRANS_NUM = 999999
errorCount = 0
descriptor_loop_length= 1
descriptor_loop_val= 8828256
result_type= (null)
r_d_type= (null)
StatusCode # 0 = 0
```

I am following a approach in which firstly I traverse each line and check for `StatusCode` after that I can split it with `=` and can get the status code but is their a easier way to achieve above mentioned ouptut?

Comment: Easier or more efficient? I would go for more efficient, and it seems to be yours.

Comment: @stribizhev efficient :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for a patter match:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "r_d_type= (null)\n" +
                  "StatusCode # 0 = 0";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("StatusCode.* = (\\d*)");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("status code: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more specific?

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking: I vote for no, don't elaborate more specific. https://regex101.com/r/uG8mQ0/1

Comment: `Pattern  p = Pattern.compile("^StatusCode.* = (\\d*)");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
   
   if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
      }
   System.out.println("not found");`  it returns not found for above string

Comment: Remove the starting ^.